# Access GPIO Hog input value

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

I'm trying to have some GPIO pins on my SoC board available by default at boot.  I've run across the gpio-hog property in the device tree documentation [here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9.41/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt), and I have my 'hogged' pin visible in userspace.  How can I see the value of that pin?  It's configured as an input.

Comment: Use character device and do some IOCTLs on top of it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish (i.e. do you want to read just levels or find edges)?  You could instead declare that GPIO as a **gpio-keys** input, and then read **/dev/input/event0** to be notified of input *transitions*.  Debounce is also supported.

Comment: I'd like to be able to read levels on it.  It's for monitoring some internal IC lines, and if at all possible be visible as a file descriptor so that the `asyncio` library in python can read it.

Comment: Consider using **extcon-gpio**: "**drivers/extcon/extcon-gpio.c** is used when you need to read an  external connector status, such as a headset line for an audio driver or an HDMI connector. It will provide a better userspace sysfs interface than GPIO."  See https://lwn.net/Articles/488285/